# How do I turn relative dB measurements into sine wave intensity?

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, librosa

So, I have gone through some analysis of an audio signal that contains a 2260Hz beep and its 4520Hz and 6780Hz components. I located these peaks and extracted their intensity in decibels.

`frequency_db_peaks = [(2261, 29), (4522, -3.6), (6783, -2.3)]`

[image: FFT graph showing three peaks, 2261Hz at 29dB, 4522 Hz at -3.6 dB, and 6783 Hz at -2.3dB]

I would like to recreate this tone with three sine waves with the appropriate amplitude to match the findings. But I'm not sure how to transform these decibel levels into sine-wave amplitude.

```py
import numpy as np

frequency_db_peaks = [(2261, 29), (4522, -3.6), (6783, -2.3)]

sr = 22050
T = 5.0
t = np.linspace(0, T, int(T*sr), endpoint=False)

signal = 0
for frequency, db in frequency_db_peaks:
    # how do I transform dB into sine-wave amplitude?
    signal = signal + amplitude * np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency*t)

ipd.Audio(signal, rate=sr)
```

How do I decide what value to use for dB floor?

How do I recreate these three tones?

Any help, including links to fundamental & supporting topics is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform dB measurements into amplitude with `librosa.db_to_amplitude`

```
signal = 0
for frequency, db in frequency_db_peaks:
    # how do I transform dB into sine-wave amplitude?
    amplitude = librosa.db_to_amplitude(db)
    signal = signal + amplitude * np.sin(2*np.pi*frequency*t)
```